# PHP mail() function not working to office email

Tags: php, email

so I'm trying to use PHP's mail() function to send an email when users register.
For some reason though, it refuses to send to the company's email. Are there some extra parameters that I might be missing that I would need for something like this, or do you think it is from the company's email filtering these emails out?

EDIT:
Here's some code:

```
$to = 'something@something.com';
$subject = 'New Web Registration';
$from = 'Quote Registration';

$headers = 'Content-type: text/html charset=iso-8859-1\r\n';
$headers .= 'From: ' . $from;

$body = '<table>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;">WebUserID:</td>
            <td>' . $wuid . '</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;">Name: </td>
            <td>' . $regdata['Name'] . '</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;">Company:</td>
            <td>' . $regdata['Company'] . '</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;">Address:</td>
            <td>' . $regdata['Address'] . '</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;">CSZ:</td>
            <td>' . $regdata['City'] . ', ' . $regdata['State'] . ' ' . $regdata['Zip'] . '</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;">Phone:</td>
            <td>' . $regdata['Phone'] . '</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;">Fax:</td>
            <td>' . $regdata['Fax'] . '</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;">URL:</td>
            <td>' . $regdata['URL'] . '</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;">Email:</td>
            <td>' . $email . '</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;">Comments:</td>
            <td>' . $regdata['Comments'] . '</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;">Customer Group:</td>
            <td>' . $regdata['CustomerGroup'] . '</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;">How Heard</td>
            <td>' . $regdata['HowHeard'] . '</td>
        </tr>
        </table>';

if (!mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    echo 'Message delivery failed.'; 
}
```

And it does successfully email to other domains such as gmail. Delivery/filter problem?

Comment: does it send email successfully to *other* domains?

Comment: Most likely a delivery/filter issue rather than your code but without the code we can't tell. Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: did you get any errors? or if the recepient was just not receiving emails?

Comment: How would we know if you're missing something if we can't see what you have?

Comment: the mail server logs are the first place to look for debugging such issues.

Comment: $body should be a valid html page, not just part of one.

Comment: the recipient is simply not receiving the emails

Comment: @alexthebake actually you don't need to re-invent the wheel. There're number of available SMTP classes you can sent emails through. Please consider using PHPMailer (google for it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is successfully sending to other domains than it is a problem with your company's mail server. It's possible that the emails are being filtered as spam or something similar.

An easy solution would be to use STMP, or you could try to find out why the are being filtered by looking at your mail server's logs.

Make sure that you send an entire html message if you're sending them as html. ( tags and all).

Answer (score 0):

i am providing you my code for sending mail. It is working fine in my application. Hope it will help you.

```
function sendmail($username)
{
    $from     =       "test@test.com";
    $to       =       "mytest@test.com";
    $subject  =       "My Test Subject";
    $body     =       "My Test Body";
    $headers .=      "From:".$from ."". "\r\n";

    if (mail($to ,$subject ,$body,$headers)) 
    {
        $msg = "Your message has been sent.";
    } 
    else
    {
        $msg = "Error in Sending the Message. Please try again.";
    }
    return $msg;
}
```

Comment: this function doesn't seem to return anything. Please add return keyword instead of $msg

Comment: The function also has a useless parameter, and hard coded fields. Pretty much a useless function.